# Push Firebase .key() to Object

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I've got a fairly simple `createService` function that sends data to my Firebase. When run it pushes my `$scope.serviceTitle` to an object called `services`, and pushes my `$scope.providerTitle` to an object called `providers`.

**main.js**

```
$scope.createService = function() {
  var newService = { title: $scope.serviceTitle };
  var newProvider = { title: $scope.providerTitle };

  var servicePromise = ServiceService.add(newService);
  var providerPromise = ProviderService.add(newProvider);
};
```

**ServiceService.js**

```
angular.module('outcomesApp').service('ServiceService', function(FBURL, $firebase) {
  var serviceRef = new Firebase(FBURL).child('services');
  var fireService = $firebase(serviceRef).$asArray();

  return {
    add: function addService(service) {
      return fireService.$add(service);
    }
  };
});
```

My data ends up looking like this:

```
{
  "services": {
    "-JgDvQz_opBMdULBPySG": {
      "title": "Hernia Repair"
    }
  },
  "providers": {
    "-JgDp4zieowSM-ymfDHR": {
      "title": "The Whittington Hospital",
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to push a third object when I run the `createService()` function, called `service_at_provider`, where `service` has a value of the the service `.key()` I just pushed, and `provider` has a value of the provider `key()`. This might help make sense of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
  "services": {
    "-JgDvQz_opBMdULBPySG": {
      "title": "Hernia Repair"
    }
  },
  "providers": {
    "-JgDp4zieowSM-ymfDHR": {
      "title": "The Whittington Hospital",
    }
  },
  "service_at_provider": {
    "-JgDvQzYxtYGp7JspWYr": {
      "service": "-JgDvQz_opBMdULBPySG", // matches the 'newService' just pushed
      "provider": "-JgDp4zieowSM-ymfDHR" // matches the 'newProvider' just pushed
    }
  }
}
```

Because of the `$add`, the `servicePromise` variable returns a promise. But I can't figure out how to return the `key()` and pass it to a new object called `service_at_provider` on the same push.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The promises returned by [$add()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata) resolve to the new firebase reference. You could do something like the following in createService.

```
$q.all([servicePromise, providerPromise]).then(function(refs) {
  var serviceRef = refs[0];
  var providerRef = refs[1];

  // service key
  serviceRef.key();

  // provider key
  providerRef.key();

  // Use that data to add to your service_at_provider array
});
```